# Adobe Search&Promote non-standard <noindex> tag

Tags: html, adobe, standards, standards-compliance

A website I am working on uses Adobe Search&Promote (SP) as it's internal website indexing and searching tool.

I need to exclude common parts of each web page from being indexed by SP (such as the header, nav, footer) because they are the same on every single page.

[SP's documentation](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/snp/8.15.0/SPguide.pdf) states the following:

> "To prevent parts of individual web pages from being searched, you can exclude portions of a page from indexing. Surround the text with `<noindex>` and `</noindex>` tags. This method is useful if you want to exclude navigation text from searches."

Of course, `<noindex>`, is not a standard HTML tag/element.

Is there javascript or something I should be doing to register/create this fake tag in browsers so I don't have to worry about any strange behavior as a result of having a non-standard HTML tag just hanging out in my code? Or should I just not care because browsers will ignore this non-existent element?

*Note: There is absolutely no styling that needs to be done on this `<noindex>` element. It simply needs to wrap around content in the HTML.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you need to do. Browsers are expected to ignore unknown tags, and they do, so they see `<noindex>foo</noindex>` just as `foo`. Well, not quite. Technically, modern browsers construct an element node (of type HTMLUnknownElement) in the DOM. But the element has no associated default styling and no associated action, so it’s really a dummy element and represents its content only.

It would be possible to remove such elements nodes using client-side JavaScript, but that would be quite unnecessary.

The only real risk is that some day some specification or some browser or some web-wide indexing robot might start treating `noindex` as a real element with some defined meaning, possibly with default rendering and default functionality. Then you would be in trouble if these differ from what you expected. But it’s a rather small risk, and it seems that you don’t have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not in the documentation, our team consulted an Adobe consultant regarding this. He told us that we can use a `'noindex'` class instead of the `<noindex>` element. He was even recommending us to use the class instead of the tag.

A warning though, the `'noindex'` class is only working with `<div>` elements but not on other elements such as `<ul>`, `<header>`, or `<footer>`.

So a usage will be something like this:

```
<div class="noindex">
   <p>This should not be indexed.</p>
</div>
```